# Create a column based on certain conditions in R

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
ROW ID  DATE         DO     CO    EID  
1    1   11/1/2010   1500    .     1
2    1   11/1/2010    300    .     1 
3    1   11/2/2010   1000    .     1
4    1   11/2/2010    750    .     1
5    1   11/2/2010      0    15    0
6    1   11/2/2010   1400    .     1
7    1   11/2/2010    300    .     1
8    2   11/4/2010    700    .     1     
9    2   11/5/2010   2000    .     1
10   2   11/6/2010      0    20    0
11   2   11/6/2010   1500    .     1  
12   2   11/6/2010    750    .     1
13   2   11/6/2010    200    .     1
14   2   11/8/2010   2500    .     1  
15   2   11/8/2010   2500    .     1
```

I want it to create a column TDD like this:

```
ROW ID  DATE         DO     CO    EID  TDD
1   1   11/1/2010   1500    .     1    1800
2   1   11/1/2010    300    .     1    1800 
3   1   11/2/2010   1000    .     1    1750
4   1   11/2/2010    750    .     1    1750
5   1   11/2/2010      0    15    0    1750
6   1   11/2/2010   1400    .     1    1700
7   1   11/2/2010    300    .     1    1700
8   2   11/4/2010    700    .     1     700
9   2   11/5/2010   2000    .     1    2000
10  2   11/6/2010      0    20    0    2000
11  2   11/6/2010   1500    .     1    2450
12  2   11/6/2010    750    .     1    2450
13  2   11/6/2010    200    .     1    2450
14  2   11/8/2010   2500    .     1    5000
15  2   11/8/2010   2500    .     1    5000
```

So the column TDD is nothing but a sum of DO values for same dates for a particular ID eg. see row 1,2 and 14,15. However, the CO values add to the complexity. Notice for rows 3 to 7, the date is the same but all five rows do not have the same TDD value. TDD value for row 6 and 7 is 1700 and not 1750 (rows 3 to 5) because in row 5 CO column has a value.

Rows 10 to 13 also have the same dates, but TDD value for row 9 is 2000 and not 2450. So, the TDD value for the row having a CO value will be the same as the TDD value preceding it for the same ID . And, rows having CO values reset the computation of TDD even if the dates are the same eg. see rows 3 to 7.

The nature of the data is such that DO and EID is 0 whenever CO column has a value. I have thousands of ID's in my data with similar structure. It would be great if you could help me with the r code to compute values for the TDD column based on the conditions above. Thank you.

Comment: There is no correlation between CO and TDD values. The CO values are arbitrarily chosen by me . I just wanted to show that when CO assumes a value, the computation of TDD needs to be reset. The TDD value 1700 you are referring to is a sum of DO values for rows 6 and 7. The TDD value 2450 is the sum of DO values for rows 11,12 and 13.

Comment: MrFlick, sorry my bad. It should be 11/2/2010 for for the DATE on row 7 in the input. How do I correct it above?

Comment: MrFlick lines 9 and 10 are not the supposed to be the same day.

Comment: @MrFlick : This is in reference to your comment on row 9 and 10. Because DO value was not recorded on 11/6/2010 i.e before CO value was recorded on 11/6/2010, the DO value on 11/5/2010 will be used to compute the TDD value for row 10. So, to correct myself the TDD value for a row having a CO value will always be TDD value in the preceding row.

Comment: You really like to make things difficult, don't you ;) I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have R 3.1 and the package zoo is not available for R 3.1. Could you modify the code to so that I don't have to use zoo library. Thank you.

Comment: I'm running `zoo` using 3.1. Sounds like you're trying to install it incorrectly. It's a very common time series package. I will not re-implement `na.locf()`. Feel free to search for other possible solutions to that part of the problem on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Then you could get the results you described with a somewhat standard `ave()` followed by a "last observation carried forward" call

```
library(zoo) #for na.locf()
dd$TDD <- with(dd, ave(DO, ID, DATE, c(0, cumsum(diff(EID)>0)), FUN=sum))
is.na(dd$TDD) <- dd$CO!="."
dd$TDD <- na.locf(dd$TDD)
```

The result is

```
   ROW ID      DATE   DO CO EID  TDD
1    1  1 11/1/2010 1500  .   1 1800
2    2  1 11/1/2010  300  .   1 1800
3    3  1 11/2/2010 1000  .   1 1750
4    4  1 11/2/2010  750  .   1 1750
5    5  1 11/2/2010    0 15   0 1750
6    6  1 11/2/2010 1400  .   1 1700
7    7  1 11/2/2010  300  .   1 1700
8    8  2 11/4/2010  700  .   1  700
9    9  2 11/5/2010 2000  .   1 2000
10  10  2 11/6/2010    0 20   0 2000
11  11  2 11/6/2010 1500  .   1 2450
12  12  2 11/6/2010  750  .   1 2450
13  13  2 11/6/2010  200  .   1 2450
14  14  2 11/8/2010 2500  .   1 5000
15  15  2 11/8/2010 2500  .   1 5000
```

which seems to match your output.

Comment: @VineetGoti Make sure you refresh the page for the latest version of the response. row 9 is 11/5 in this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate it MrFlick.

Comment: I have R 3.1 and the package zoo is not available for R 3.1. Could you modify the code to so that I don't have to use zoo library. Thank you.